# Which sums-of-two-squares are totients?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Consider the two subsets of the natural numbers $A$, $B$ given by
$$A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mathrel: \text{$\exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $n = x^2 + y^2$}\}$$
and
$$B = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : \exists m \in \mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. } n = \phi(m)\}$$
where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.

We know that the intersection of the two sets $A$, $B$ contains infinitely many elements. Indeed, for $C \subset \mathbb{N}$, put $C(X)$ for the number of elements in $C$ satisfying $n \leq X$. Then
$$(A \cap B)(X) \gg X (\log X)^{-3/2},$$
since for a prime $p$ of the form $p = x^2 + y^2 + 1$, we have $p-1 \in A \cap B$, since $\phi(p) = p-1$. The density comes from a theorem of H. Iwaniec from 1972; see also the update [On a theorem of Bredihin and Linnik](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06648) by Friedlander and Iwaniec.

By multiplicativity, if $p_1, \cdots, p_k$ are primes of the above form then

$$\displaystyle \phi(p_1 \cdots p_k) \in A \cap B.$$

Is there a nice way to characterize the set $A \cap B$? Failing that, what is a better estimate for the density of $A \cap B$?

Comment: I did some very iffy heuristics (based on a number in $[1,X]$ has $\log\log X$ prime factors, which I assumed were like one in each $[e^{e^i},e^{e^{i+1}}]$ for $i=1,\ldots,\log\log X$) and ended up with an estimate for $(A\cap B)(X)$ which is smaller than your lower bound(!) My tentative conclusion from this is that the dominant term in $(A\cap B)(X)$ actually comes from the $\phi(p)$ that you're already looking at.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas the example extends to numbers of the form $n = p_1 \cdots p_k$, where $p_j = x_j^2 + y_j^2 + 1$, by multiplicativity

Comment: Banks, Luca, Saidak, and Shparlinski showed that the number of $m\le X$ with $\phi(m)$ a sum of two squares is $O(X/(\log X)^{3/2})$. Since $\phi(m) \le x$ implies that $m \ll x\log\log{x}$, this gives an upper bound of the shape $x/(\log{x})^{3/2+o(1)}$ for the count you are after. Probably one can remove the "$o(1)$", and get $\ll x/(\log{x})^{3/2}$, by fine tuning the BLSS arguments. (This is suggested by the very rapid decay of the distribution function of $m/\phi(m)$.)